# I need different button titles for different users in telegram group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm going to make vote-bot based on Schulze-method, so I need to show individual buttons for every user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**No possible** to make different inline keyboard for each user in same chat at this time.

But I think you can use a button with `url` parameter contain `https://t.me/Bot?start=vote_uniqueId`, and when user click it, your bot will receive `/start vote_uniqueId`. And then you can give they different keyboard to vote now. :)